# How print first largest value Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium

My code:

```
          List<WebElement> myList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='legends']//span[4]"));
            //To store all web elements into list
          List<String> all_elements_text=new ArrayList<String>();
          for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++) {
              all_elements_text.add(myList.get(i). getText());
              System.out.println(myList.get(i).getText());                              
            }
          Object obj = Collections.max(all_elements_text);
            System.out.println("The highest value :"+ obj);
}
```

My Output

```
35.6%
22.6%
15.8%
13.8%
7.4%
4.2%
0.7%
The highest value :7.4%
```

It's wrong. I want to print the first largest value.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You are storing the values as strings - and therefore they are treated as words in a dictionary. 7 is higher than 0,1,2,3 and 4, so it gets treated as the maximum lexicographically. You could try and store 7.4 as 07.4 - or simply store the values in an ArrayList<Double> and leave the percent sign out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a custom `comparator` to do this as `compareTo` method of `String` class will perform text based comparison and hence, 7.4 will be compared higher than 35 (because of 7 being higher than 3). Here's java 8 example, e.g.:

```
List<String> all_elements_text = new ArrayList<>();
all_elements_text.add("35.6%");
all_elements_text.add("7.4%");
DecimalFormat df =  new DecimalFormat("0.0#%");
Optional<String> max = all_elements_text.stream()
    .max((s1, s2) -> {
        try {
            return Double.valueOf(df.parse(s1).doubleValue()).
                    compareTo(Double.valueOf(df.parse(s2).doubleValue()));
        }catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
if(max.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(max.get());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you compare as `String` the 7 at the start of 7.4% is the max value

If you mean to compare by number as Double you need to define a different List as:

```
List<Double> all_elements_text=new ArrayList<Double>();
```

and add Double values

```
all_elements_text.add(Double.parseDouble(myList.get(i). getText().replace("%", "")));
```

And add % to the print in the end:

```
System.out.println("The highest value :"+ obj + "%");
```